# How to add subtitle to the LargeTopAppBar in jetpack compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, material-components-android, android-jetpack-compose-material3

I have a problem with adding subtitle to the *TopAppBar* *Composable*. I am trying to implement *LargeTopAppBar* from *Material Design 3*, but with extra subtitle on it. The issue I am currently facing is that it renders twice. Below is my *Composable*:

```
@Composable
private fun HomeTopBar(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    title: String,
    subtitle: String,
    navigateToProfileScreen: () -> Unit,
    navigateToAboutScreen: () -> Unit
) {
    LargeTopAppBar(
        modifier = modifier,
        title = {
            Column {
                Text(
                    text = title,
                    style = MaterialTheme.typography.headlineMedium,
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onSurface
                )
                Text(
                    text = subtitle,
                    style = MaterialTheme.typography.titleSmall,
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onSurfaceVariant
                )
            }
        },
        actions = {
            NavigationDropDownMenu(
                navigateToProfileScreen = navigateToProfileScreen,
                navigateToAboutScreen = navigateToAboutScreen
            )
        },
    )
}
```

For some reason it renders twice. I think that this problem is related to the fact that this top app bar has 2 modes (pinned and expanded).

**Visual preview:**
Here is preview of my composable function to highlight the problem:
[image: Preview of my top app bar composable]

**Dependencies I used in the project:**
implementation 'androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.0.0-beta01'
compose_version = '1.3.0-beta01'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remove the `color` attribute inside the Text elements in the title and subtitle.

```
Text(
        text = title,
        style = MaterialTheme.typography.headlineMedium,
        //color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onSurface
    )
```

Currently you can only define the same color for both `Text` using the **`colors`** attribute in the `LargeTopAppBar` :

```
LargeTopAppBar(
       colors = TopAppBarDefaults.largeTopAppBarColors(
          titleContentColor=MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onSurface
       ),
       //... 
)
```

Finally use only M3 components (`androidx.compose.material3.*`) in the `LargeTopAppBar`, not M2 (`androidx.compose.material.*`) components.

[image].
[image]

Comment: Thanks, this works fine as a temporary solution, because I would like to have it with different colors. 

I will have to probably write my own custom LargeTopAppBar based on the material design code.